# Site max-width not working in internet explorer

Tags: css

Why does the width of my site stretch to the edges of the browser in Internet Explorer? What am I missing?

```
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%; }

.site-main {
padding: 10vw 10vw 5vw;
max-width: 1110px; }
@media (min-width: 1440px) {
.site-main {
  padding: 154px 154px 77px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto; } }
@media (max-width: 760px) {
.site-main {
  padding: 5vw 5vw 5vw; }
}
```

I believe this code covers the relevant parts.

Comment: may be your screen size is smaller that what you u have set as `max-width: 1110px;`

Comment: It’s not. I’ve tested on multiple screens and resolutions.

Comment: Because you're relying on padding, not margins.

Comment: set `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;` to the class `.site-main` instead of adding it in `@media (min-width: 1440px)`

Answer (score 0):

Padding just puts space around the content, but not around the edges of the div with your `site-main` class.

Here is a fiddle with your code, changed padding to margin, and some color added to show the difference:

https://jsfiddle.net/qxp098j3/4/

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; 
}

.site-main {
    margin: 10vw 10vw 5vw;
    max-width: 1110px;
    background-color:Blue;
}

@media (min-width: 1440px) {
    .site-main {
        margin: 154px 154px 77px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 760px) {
    .site-main {
        margin: 5vw 5vw 5vw; 
    }
}


<body>
    <div class="site-main">
       blah blah blah
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You could have fixed the hideous formatting whilst you were at it :p

Comment: ...in fact, if you had, you may have spotted the syntax error.

Comment: okay, but only cause you said "whilst"... and that always makes me laugh

Answer (score 0):

@jeremy, please check the below working example in your browser(based on your css, with some minor modifications) and see if that issue still exists.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.site-main {
  padding: 10vw 10vw 5vw;
  max-width: 1110px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
@media (min-width: 1440px) {
  .site-main {
    padding: 154px 154px 77px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 760px) {
  .site-main {
    padding: 5vw 5vw 5vw;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="site-main" style="background: #eee">&nbsp;</div>
```